# Trying to render two different views in one template according to their specific url routing

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

Im trying to render **login** and **register** view in a single template using variable assignment and if-else. I'm sorry if its a rookie mistake, Im pretty new to this..

github repo- https://github.com/varundhand/DevSearch

my urls.py :-

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('login/',views.loginUser,name='login'),
  path('logout/',views.logoutUser,name='logout'),
  path('register/',views.registerUser,name='register'),

  path('',views.profiles,name='profiles'),
  path('profile/<str:pk>/',views.userProfile,name='user-profile'),
]
```

my views.py :-

```
def loginUser(request):
  page = "login"
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('profiles')

  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    try: 
      user = User.objects.get(username=username) 
    except:
      messages.error(request,'Username doesnt exist')

    user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password) 

    if user is not None:
      login(request,user) 
      return redirect ('profiles')
    else:
      messages.error(request,'Username/Password incorrect')

  context = {page:'page'}
  return render(request, 'users/login_register.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
  logout(request)
  messages.error(request,'User was logged out!')
  return redirect('login')

def registerUser(request):
  page = "register"
  context= {page:'page'}
  return render(request,'users/login_register.html', context)
```

my html template file :-

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% if page == "register" %}
  <h1>Register User</h1>

  <p>Already have an account? <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> </p>

{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="pass`your text`word" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">

  <p>Dont have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a></p>
</form>

{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

**My Approach**
I gave variable assignment of page='login' and page='register' in loginUser and registerUser view respectively and then i gave an if-else in my common template but for some reason only loginUser view is working even when i go to the register url.

Comment: In your context dict, you have {page:'page'} instead of {'page':page} Because of that in your template you have context value 'register' with value 'page'

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my silly question, I was passing the wrong context dictionary i.e. it shoulda been context = {'page':page}